# Не работает поддержка переноса Android-приложения на карту памяти

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! В соответствии с прочитанным на **developers.android.com**, я добавил в манифест своего андроид приложения атрибут `installLocation="auto"` но кнопка "Перенести на SD-карту" в настройках так и не стала активной.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ua.leonidius.filer" installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
 />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Это должно помочь: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location
и: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена: надо было написать `android:installLocation="auto"`, а не просто `installLocation="auto"`